# protect the program from buffer overflow?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I got a small program which is vulnerable to buffer overflow. For example, the arrays are limited to 8 characters, but still I am able to more to it. I realized that gets() is vulnerable so I planned to use fgets(). This this function, I am getting segmentation error.

Also, other recommendations are welcome.

Thank you

```
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
int valid = 0;    
char str1[8];    
char str2[8];
printf ("Enter value for str1: ") ;

fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);  

printf ("Enter value for str2: ") ;

fgets(str2, sizeof(str2), stdin);

if (strncmp (str1, str2, 8) == 0)  
{       valid = 1;
}
printf("buffer: str1(%s), str2(%s), valid(%d)\n", str1, str2, valid);   
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code which is supposed to work, using `fgets`. You've already told us what's wrong with the given program.

Comment: First off don't use `gets()`

Comment: You can use `gets_s()` instead.

Comment: I changed gets() for fgets(). I posted gets() initially because that was a code which works and I asked for help. Hopefully, now we understand each other.

Comment: @user3131067 show the new code with `fgets` that results in segfault.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/tODsxv). How did you get a segfault?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Why the rollback? The original question contained `gets` and the only answer addresses `gets`, so I think it should stay in the question.

Comment: @mafso The code originally posted contained `gets`, but it did not match the actual question. See the above comments.

Answer (score 2):

Please reference: [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-dangerous-why-should-it-not-be-used) I understand that you indicated that you already know `gets` is a vulnerable keyword to use in C but you still provided code for using `gets`...

When trying to get or store strings it is more preferable to use `fgets` as the format follows a buffer of space to read in strings or characters from the user: `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`.